# Noah's Ark Question Tax

Tags: discussion

I'd like to have a charity to link people who drop by to ask random Noah's Ark questions linked to a post on meta, not just to razzle them a little, but because it might do some good.  Could someone suggest a good Noah's Ark related charity?  Maybe someone group who takes care of random animals (but doesn't also hate humans) or those guys who actually remade Noah's Ark?

Then, whenever someone asks a Noah's Ark related question, after giving the the common salutation and informing them how they might improve their post (unless it actually meets the community guidelines) post a link to the top-rated post on this question.

```
 ... and because you asked a question about Noah's ark, don't forget to pay the perfunctory [Noah's Ark question tax](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6926/4)
```

Comment: I was going to suggest the United Bible Societies as something everyone should be able to get behind, but it doesn't look like they actually have a donate page!

Answer (score 4):

The [World Wildlife Fund](https://support.worldwildlife.org/site/SPageServer?pagename=main_monthly&s_src=AWE2007OQ18299A01179RX) is pretty good and mostly sensible in their mission, which is environmental preservation and minimizing negative impact from human activity. Many major zoos around the world are associated with them.

Comment: When it comes to other animal groups, I have trouble personally supporting them because they are either far too radical in their preference for animals *over* humans, or their approach to helping animals is actually harmful.

Answer (score -2):

You may pay your Noah's Ark Question tax here at [answers in Genesis](https://answersingenesis.org/donate/), thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: It's a funny idea, but I don't think AiG is a neutral enough organisation to promote like this. As a creationist even I wouldn't support them enough ;)

Comment: I don't know anything about 'em (other than they're another answer when singing "Who Built the Ark") so if you can suggest another less controversial charity, it's fine by me!